# Show content of dynamically created collapsible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this program that can dynamically create collapsibles. Everything seems to work fine, expect for when I click on one of the created collapsibles the content of the collapsible  isn't shown, and I'm unsure why. I tried something like this to toggle the content, but it didn't work:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    console.log("opened content")
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

**Here is my full code:**

```js
var elementCounter = 0;
var elementCounterContent = 0;
var text;
function addElement() {
  text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  
  var newDiv = $("<button class='collapsible'></button>").text(text);
  var newContentOfDiv = $("<div class='content'><input type='text'></div>");

  newDiv.id = 'temp' + elementCounter;
  newContentOfDiv.id = 'content' + elementCounterContent;
  console.log(newDiv.id);
  console.log(newContentOfDiv.id);

  newDiv.classList = "div";
  elementCounter++
  elementCounterContent++
  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM

  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";
  $("body").append(newDiv, newContentOfDiv);
}


var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    console.log("opened content")
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input" type="text"><button onclick="addElement()">Add</button>
```

Comment: The content isn't toggled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't adding your event listeners...

```js
var elementCounter = 0;
var elementCounterContent = 0;
var text;
function addElement() {
  text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  
  var newDiv = $("<button class='collapsible'></button>").text(text);
  var newContentOfDiv = $("<div class='content'><input type='text'></div>");

  newDiv.id = 'temp' + elementCounter;
  newContentOfDiv.id = 'content' + elementCounterContent;
  //console.log(newDiv.id);
  //console.log(newContentOfDiv.id);

  newDiv.classList = "div";
  elementCounter++
  elementCounterContent++
  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM

  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";
  $("body").append(newDiv, newContentOfDiv);

  //add the event listener to the newly created element...
  newDiv.click(function() {
  //thankfully, you did most of the heavy lifting.
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });


//this needed to be moved inside of your function...
//however you shouldn't need the loop...
/*
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    console.log(content);
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
*/
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input" type="text"><button onclick="addElement()">Add</button>
```

Comment: @hp2345 there was an error and I had to update the snippet, so it should run 100% correct...